# python utf-8 japanese

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have some Japanese words I wish to convert to utf-8, as shown below:

```
jap_word1 = u'中山'
jap_word2 = u'小倉'

print jap_word1.encode('utf-8') # Doesn't work 
print jap_word2.encode('utf-8') # Prints properly
```

Why is it that one word can be converted properly to utf-8 and printed to show the same characters but not the other?

(I am using python 2.6 on Windows 7 Ultimate)

Comment: Presumably the second print is meant to be word2?

Comment: THankss for pointing that out. Corrected it.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use "jp" as an abbreviation for Japanese instead of "jap" to avoid racist connotations. In this context, it's blindingly obvious what you mean... but I still noticed. And jp is standard.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was strange too

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things must align to print characters properly:

1. What encoding is the script saved in?
2. Do you have a `# coding: xxxx` statement in your script, where xxxx matches the encoding the file is saved in?
3. Does your output terminal support your encoding?  `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding`
   a. If not, can you change the console encoding? (`chcp` command on Windows)
4. Does the font you are using support the characters?

Saving the script in UTF-8, this works in both PythonWin and IDLE.

```
# coding: utf-8
jap_word1 = u'中山'
jap_word2 = u'小倉'

print jap_word1
print jap_word2
```

Interestingly, I got your results with the `.encode('utf-8')` added to both prints in IDLE, but it worked correctly in Pythonwin, whose default output window supports UTF-8.

Idle is a strange beast.  `sys.stdout.encoding` on my system produces `'cp1252'`, which doesn't support Asian characters, but it prints the first word wrong and the second one right when printing in UTF-8.

Comment: When I do this from the python console in Ubuntu, I don't encounter any problems either. But for Python IDLE in Windows 7, goodness ...

Answer (score 0):

Because your console is not in UTF-8. Run `chcp 65001` before running.

Comment: I'm using the Python IDLE. The funny thing is that only some characters are being converted correctly but not the rest.